# How to use the log to trigger an event (sending acknowledgement) to send a notification email

Tags: excel, mule, datamapper

Is there a way to use the messages on the log to trigger a notification for me to be able to parse and send an email with the warnings and errors?

I'm also looking at errors or warnings from the datamapper if there are records that failed since I have set the bad input policy parameter to be lenient. I believe I should be able to call a class of some sort.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do like below

1) If your using Mule management console (MMC), then using MMC alert mechanism you can search for specific string format in log files and raise mails.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-management-console/v/3.7/working-with-alerts

2) Another option, you can write a flow that will read the file for every few minutes and search for the string and do actions accordingly.

I can suggest option 1 is best solution for these type of scenarios.

Comment: Hi Rama, Thanks for the comments. I'm thinking if it will be able to handle mapping errors like bad input and allow other records to be processed. I just need to have an alert once bad input comes in but process the remaining records. thanks!

Comment: Also, the datamapper warnings are not showing up in the log files.  Do you have a way to print the warnings on the file?